# Using username and password from an existing database table to authenticate in Blazor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Is there a simple way to use username data from another existing SQL Server database table to authenticate in the login Blazor server template?

I have this form in the Login.cshtml

```
<form id="account" method="post">
    <h5>Usa il tuo account per accedere al sito.</h5>
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
            <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Accedi</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my Login.cshtml.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace BbcSrUI.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, 
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to link an existing DB table with username and password to check if the input user is valid.

Thank you!

Comment: Blazor is still a web application. It doesn't have a different authentication mechanism, it still uses ASP.NET Core Identity. It's the same as any other ASP.NET Core application - especially Blazor Server-side. What does `from another existing sql db table` mean? The `AspNetUsers` table from an existing ASP.NET Core application? Something else?

Comment: I have a table where there are usr and psw from an old web site and I want to use this data into my blazor project. I use the template with the individual athentication enable. Sorry, is my first time in web dev

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create your own authentication system, check if the entered passwords match, and generate a cookie or JWT token. I advise against this though for security reasons.

You should use the Identity system that comes with ASP.NET. In there you have the `UserManager` class that can be used to authenticate users.

First, add this to your services collection:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

`UserDbContext` is the database context that will be used by the `UserManager`. It inherits from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` or `IdentityDbContext`.

After that, in order to log in users, if you want to do it through an API, you can do something like this:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginModel.Username);

            if ((user is not null) && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginModel.Password))
            {
                IList<string> userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                List<Claim> authClaims = new()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
                    new Claim(Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, "pwd")
                };

                foreach (string role in userRoles)
                {
                    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                }

                SymmetricSecurityKey authSigningKey = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));
                //SymmetricSecurityKey authSigningKey = Startup.SecurityAppKey;

                JwtSecurityToken token = new(
                    issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                    audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                    claims: authClaims,
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                    );

                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    expiration = token.ValidTo
                });
            }

            return Unauthorized();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading our question I wrote a template project that explains how to handle authentication in Blazor.

Authentication in Blazor is too complex for a complete answer here.

Objective are

- Being DB agnostic
- Support multi language
- Support page reload

https://github.com/iso8859/AspNetCoreAuthMultiLang