# Migrating ASP.NET Webforms FormsAuthentication to Blazor

Tags: webforms, blazor, blazor-server-side, maui

We would like to upgrade excising ASP.NET Webforms website to Blazor.

What is the best approach to upgrade or even to use an existing SQL forms authentication database tables in order to use the same users data in the new Blazor website ?

Comment: Server side or WebAssembly???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using username and password from an existing database table to authenticate in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70069122/using-username-and-password-from-an-existing-database-table-to-authenticate-in-b)

Comment: Server Side. We would like to upgrade to Blazor existing website with the customers login data that is built with FormsAuthentication

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question here:
https://travis.io/blog/2015/03/24/migrate-from-aspnet-membership-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).